# Firebase authentication resend verification code in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

How can i resend phone number auth verification code using firebase api?

What i did try:

```
//Receiving verfication id and request for verification code
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
  if let error = error {
    self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }
}

let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
    withVerificationID: verificationID,
    verificationCode: verificationCode)

//Verify verification code
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
  if let error = error {
    let authError = error as NSError
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have no custom design then you can use FirebaseUI for this authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Call requestOtp() method on resend OTP button click.

```
import FirebaseAuth

func requestOtp() {
        let phNo = "Your phone number"
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phNo, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
            // ...
            UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
        }
}
```

.

Verify Code with Auth:

```
func verifyNumberWith(verificationCode: String) {
        let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID")
        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
            withVerificationID: verificationID ?? "",
            verificationCode: verificationCode)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            //Do your actions. 
        }
    }
```

If you face any problem in the above code, please let me know in comment.

Happy to help!

Comment: Thanks mohit for your response but its normal process of receiving verification code, not resend way. i'm looking for a way to doing it by api.

Comment: You can use the above method to resend code from the app. But if you want it to do via API please update your question.